# What's the best, most compatible sub-$100 graphics card for Natty?

Tags: 11.04, graphics, performance

Since upgrading to Natty graphic performance has been absolutely terrible despite having decent system specs. I'm willing to buy a new card if it will make the interface fast again. Can someone suggest a card that will perform well and be totally compatible out of the box with Natty?

Comment: It would help if you mentioned what card you have now, maybe it's a configuration problem we can fix.

Comment: Hey, it's an onboard ATI 4250. Worked great with 10.10, very fast compiz effects, with 11.04 has been terrible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a truly "**Out of the box**" experience you should buy any Intel Graphics Adapter (this also applies if you don't like proprietary drivers).
If you prefer a bit more performance and accept an "**Out of the box** *in the second attempt*" experience you should consider buying a Nvidia or ATI card (the only thing needed here is to install the proprietary driver on the first start).
In my experience a Pentium IV 2800MHz with 1GB of ram and a Nvidia 6200 AGP works smoothly with Natty (as you can see it's a five/six year old computer).

Answer (score 1):

Simply look for nVidia cards because they are a lot better supported. You'll get better experience and drivers will be more commonly updated. I have ATI and i am not happy..ever.